# Atualizar DataGridView em c# via Trigger UPDATE SQL

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, trigger

Olá, tenho a seguinte dúvida.

Estou realizando uma aplicação em c# com banco de dados SQL Server.

Tenho um **DataGridView** onde ele é carregado via **DataTable**, as informações carregadas são de pessoas: Nome, Status ...

Quero que, quando realizar um update em status(muda de off-line para on-line) Atualize o **DataGridView** automaticamente.

Atualmente faço isso com um time, que fica a cada 15 segundos atualizando o form, mas acho isso inviável, e se eu precisa atualizar o form a cada 1 segundo?
e se for 100000 mil pessoas?

Como posso fazer isso via trigger Update:

Meu Pensamento:

Trigger update que chama alguma procedure de select ou apenas o comando `Select * from pessoa` , aplicação c# captura esse select e o insere no DataGridView.

EX:
Consegui Chegar a isso:

```
>CREATE TABLE PESSOA(

NOME VARCHAR(250)

)
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER SELECIONAR_NOME ON DBO.PESSOA
AFTER UPDATE AS 

BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM PESSOA

END
```

Inserindo Valores na Tabela

```
 INSERT INTO PESSOA(NOME) VALUES ('fulano1')
 INSERT INTO PESSOA(NOME) VALUES ('fulano2')
 INSERT INTO PESSOA(NOME) VALUES ('fulano3')
 INSERT INTO PESSOA(NOME) VALUES ('fulano4')
 INSERT INTO PESSOA(NOME) VALUES ('fulano5')
```

```
UPDATE PESSOA SET NOME = 'fulano0' WHERE NOME = 'fulano1'
```

RESULTADO:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como consigo pegar essa tabela? A tabela que saiu da trigger After Update?

Comment: Apresente o código e aponte exatamente onde está a sua dúvida. Ps.: NUNCA faça `SELECT * FROM`

Comment: Man, não é uma dúvida, pergunto se tem uma forma melhor de fazer o que citei como faço, não preciso postar código pq ali da pra entender perfeitamente.

Tem um **Clock** que a cada 15 seg fica dando select na tabela apenas isso...

Comment: Eu entendi... mas dessa forma a pergunta fica fora de escopo por não apresentar um [MCVE]

Comment: Man o que você falou é de problema, eu não estou com uma difículdade no código, não é um bug que não sei resolver, estou perguntando a melhor forma, como vou postar um forma melhor de você enxergar o problema(mínimo) se ele não existe?
Toda a informação está inclusa.
É verificável quando eu testar e me certificar que dessa forma funciona e ficar mais intuitivo e não apenas algo atualizando a cada certo tempo

Comment: http://prntscr.com/n380i6

Comment: Cara, existem N práticas e abordagens para trabalhar com esse tipo de problema por tanto a questão se torna muito ampla. Acho que você deveria considerar um `SELECT * FROM Pessoa` a cada `x` segundos, como um um ponto de revisão do seu código, tendo em vista que já está preocupado com escala e performance

Comment: O que postei foi apenas um exemplo, coloquei o "código" que fiz agora, para ver se exemplifica melhor a minha dúvida